# MySQL join two tables in two different databases hosted in different servers

Tags: mysql, join

I have two databases, say **A** and **B**.
**A** is hosted on my local machine while **B** is hosted in a different IP.
Now, is it possible to join **table1** from database **A** with **table2** from database **B**. If yes, How can I acheive that?

Well, if this is relevant, I am working on php codeigniter.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible, assuming you have the correct permissions on both databases to do the join.  Check the duplicate link for the exact syntax.

Comment: In the duplicate link it is discussed about two tables. So i assume you are saying that once both the databases are open it doesn't matter where they are hosted? And that actually makes sense.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have edited the question and it is more about the permission now. Can you offer any help here?

Comment: You've largely changed your original question, which was a duplicate.  I would recommend that you just open a new question, as this one will not get any views at this point.